# rxjs limit retries on socket reconnect

Tags: javascript, sockets, rxjs

I'm currently following [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vanilla-js-rxjs-websocket) example and I'm tring to extend upon it with my own logic.

I can get the socket to connect, but I see that there is a problem in having the client reconnect continuously - Hence why I want to have a limit on the number of retries that the client can perform.

```
socket.pipe(
    tap((data => console.log(data))),
    retryWhen((errors) =>
        errors.pipe(
            take(this.retryCount),
            delayWhen(val =>
                timer(val * 1000)
            )
        )
    )
).subscribe()
```

I looked up the documentation and figured that I could use the `take()` operator from rxjs. However, given that I set my retryCount to 5, the following scenario can be assumed:

- Client connects to socket successfully
- Client disconnects from the socket
- Client reconnects after 4 retries
- Client disconnects
- Client retries 1 times, and stops retrying (`take(5)` has been reached)

Is there a way, in which I can "reset" the amount of times that `take()` will retry? i.e. so that every time the client disconnects from the socket, it will always have 5 retries?

Comment: Where does the connect and disconnect happen? You can hook into that mechanism to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The `retryWhen` logic from your example doesn't take into account all the possible intertwined flows of connect/disconnect/reconnect. Also the reset of the reconnection attempts doesn't happen.

Beside that, you're touching the inner Observables for open and close of the webSocket directly (which is not technically wrong), while you could put all the logic and handlers inside the subject's pipe and  subscription code. I've forked your example from StackBlitz and adjusted it so that any connect / disconnect and reconnect events are handled properly.

As you can see in the screenshot below, it's trying to reconnect five time before it reaches the limit and quit.

[image]

The number of reconnect retries and the delay between each trial can be tweaked via this two constants:

```
const maxReconnectAttempts = 5; // -1 stands for 'forever'
const reconnectAttemptDelay = 1000; // in ms
```

As written in the comment, if you put `const maxReconnectAttempts = -1` the reconnection trials will go on forever.

You can find below the whole code taken from `index.js`, or [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vanilla-js-rxjs-websocket-apervf?file=index.js) in the forked StackBlitz repo for the full reference.

```
import { iif, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, delay, retryWhen, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { webSocket } from 'rxjs/webSocket';

// get elements
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

const display = document.getElementById('app');
const msg = document.getElementById('msg');

// bind click actions
btn1.onclick = connect;
btn2.onclick = disconnect;

// create a webSocketSubject
const wsUrl = 'wss://www.gasnow.org/ws/gasprice';
const maxReconnectAttempts = 5; // -1 stands for 'forever'
const reconnectAttemptDelay = 1000; // in ms

let wsSubject$;
let wsSubscription;
let disconnected = false;
let reconnectRetryCount = 0;

// display live data on view
const bindDataToView = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data);
  display.innerText = Number(data.rapid);
};

// connect/subscribe to websocket url
function connect() {
  if (!this.wsSubject || this.wsSubject.closed) {
    wsSubject$ = webSocket(wsUrl); // create a fresh instance

    console.log(`Initializing WebSocket connection to ${wsUrl}...`);

    wsSubscription = wsSubject$
      .pipe(
        retryWhen((errors) =>
          errors.pipe(
            concatMap((error) =>
              iif(
                () =>
                  maxReconnectAttempts !== -1 &&
                  reconnectRetryCount++ >= maxReconnectAttempts,
                throwError('WebSocket reconnecting retry limit exceeded!'),
                of(error).pipe(
                  tap(() => {
                    disconnected = true;
                    console.warn('Trying to reconnect to WebSocket server...');
                  }),
                  delay(reconnectAttemptDelay)
                )
              )
            )
          )
        ),
        tap(() => {
          if (disconnected) {
            disconnected = false;
            reconnectRetryCount = 0;

            msg.innerText = 'Streaming ...';
            console.log('Successfully reconnected to the WebSocket server.');
          }
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          msg.innerText = 'Streaming ...';
          bindDataToView(data);
        },
        (err) => {
          reconnectRetryCount = 0;
          console.error(err);
        },
        () => {
          reconnectRetryCount = 0;
          msg.innerText = 'Connection closed';

          console.warn('Connection to the WebSocket server was closed!');
        }
      );
  }
}

// close websocket connection
function disconnect() {
  if (wsSubject$) {
    wsSubject$.complete(); // this will trigger closingObserver and closeObserver
    wsSubject$.unsubscribe();
    wsSubject$ = null;

    disconnected = true;
    reconnectRetryCount = 0;

    if (wsSubscription) {
      wsSubscription.unsubscribe();
      wsSubscription = null;
    }

    console.log('Disconnected from the WebSocket server.');
  }
}
```